# Which utility type requires in TypeScript to specify type based on other nested type?

Tags: typescript

How to extract type `{ alpha: number; bravo: string; }` from `type Test`?

```
type Test = {
  foo: {
    alpha: number;
    bravo: string;
  }
}

//             ↓ Utility type which I want to know
type SubTest = UtilityType<Test, "foo">;

// Must be same as:
type SubTest = {
  alpha: number;
  bravo: string;
}
```

Please note that in this question `SubTest` must refer to `Test` but not conversely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), what you want is to access the value of the property key 'foo', which you do using square bracket notation.  This is called a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).

```
type Subtype = Type['foo']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8CwAoKUBmA9gQFzra64CGANmABaWkB2ArgLYBGEATgNzkUO3SgDcSURNwCWTAOb8cUAL7YVWbKEhQAyiw5xEKWAmABtAOSEC5gLq8oAegdQp8dFBr1GUVpx72hUXFJGXllIA)

Comment: Known as a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) or "indexed access" type.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you!  I blanked on the word "lookup type" and couldn't find the docs page that I needed when I searched "typescript square brackets".  So in all fairness to the question asker here, it can be really hard to find information without knowing the right terminology.

Comment: Yeah, the docs are pretty scattered and don't tend to keep up very well with the pace of the introduction of new language features.  I mean, other than release notes, which is one reason why it's hard to find things.

Comment: And yes, I prematurely pattern-matched on "which utility type is required" and thought "homework question" instead of actually looking and seeing that they didn't want a built-in utility type at all.  Oh well!